# insert to the dbf file does not accept null values

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dbf

I've got a dbf file which I want to execute query. This is my code (.net 4.0, C# Windows Forms):

```
oconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=" + path + ";Collating Sequence=machine";
oconn.Open();
OleDbCommand ocmd = oconn.CreateCommand();
string na = TBNazwaKonta.Text.Replace("\n","");
na = na.Replace("\r","") ;
string ks2 = ks.Replace("\n","");
ks2 = ks2.Replace("\r", "");
string zapytanie = @"insert into " + path + " (rk, Na,Ks,Ss,So,Wyr,Bw,Bm,Ow,Om,Wm,Mm,Pm,Pw,Ks1,Ks2,Ks3,Ks4,Llx,Wn01,Ma01,L01,Wn02,Ma02,L02,Wn03,Ma03,L03,Wn04,Ma04,L04,Wn05,Ma05,L05,Wn06,Ma06,L06,Wn07,Ma07,L07,Wn08,Ma08,L08,Wn09,Ma09,L09,Wn10,Ma10,L10,Wn11,Ma11,L11,Wn12,Ma12,L12) values (0,'Z-Dz PROD.OPAKOWAŃKIEWICZA 108   38-200 ', '200 02 000212',0,0,'',0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,'','','','',0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0)";
ocmd.CommandText = zapytanie;
ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
oconn.Close();
```

Connection is fine, insert query is fine too, but I want to know why this dbf does not accept null values.

Where could I check that dbf accepts nulls? When I using an program to read dbfs and I execute a query then dbf accepts null. It not accept only when I use ado.net. 
Thanks for any help solving my problem

Comment: Some of the columns do not accept NULL?  Not answerable without the table definition. Also add exact error msg + stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

You may create a new Command and execute it before insertion.

```
OleDbCommand dbCmdNull = oconn.CreateCommand();
dbCmdNull.CommandText = "SET NULL OFF";
dbCmdNull.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I want. It's working well now!. Thank you for really fast answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can set your columns not to accept nulls.

If you are using visual foxpro, open your dbf, go to View > Table Designer
You will see the list of columns, last column indicates if it accepts nulls.

There a button for Null there. Uncheck that, and your columns will not accept nulls.

This will ensure that you don't write nulls. But if there are nulls, you are writing them somewhere. You will have to fix that bit of code.